# Complete missing lines using rgl grid3d

Tags: r, graphics, 3d, rgl

Does anyone know of a way to 1) complete the missing gridlines in the `grid3d` call for `y`, and 2) draw horizontal gridlines to close the top of the grids constructed by the `grid3d` calls for `x` and `y`?  I've played around with various combinations of `pretty` calls within `grid3d` to no avail and am wondering if this is an `rgl` quirk or a misspecification on my part.  Additionally, I'd like to extend the vertical axis numbering to wherever the closed grids end up.

```
library(rgl)
cpts <- seq(0, 2, length = 40)
spts <- seq(0, 1, length = 20)
grid <- expand.grid(s=spts, c=cpts)
UFn  <- function(s,c){c^(0.5) - exp(s) + 1}
U    <- UFn(grid$s, grid$c)
open3d()
rgl.surface(x = spts, y = matrix(U,nrow = 40, ncol = 20), z = cpts, 
            coords = c(1,3,2), specular = "black")
axes3d("x", at = pretty(spts, n = 2), color = "black")
axes3d("y", at = pretty(cpts, n = 5), color = "black")
axes3d("z--", color = "black")
grid3d("x")
grid3d("y", at = pretty(spts, n = 2))
title3d(xlab ='s', ylab = 'c', zlab = 'U', color = "black")
rgl.snapshot("3d.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is a bug. You don't get any z-lines when using `grid3d("y",n=2)` even though it should be the same. You can work around it by using the list specification of at, setting the x element of the list, eg:

```
grid3d("y", at = list(x=pretty(spts, n = 2)))
```